# How to create and use a new pgf key

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

In this example, I would like to have a new key `NbGrad` then I could write :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=6cm,font=\footnotesize,NbGrad=12]
```

And use the key as I use `\NbGrad` or another way if it is better :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=6cm,font=\footnotesize]
\def\NbGrad{12}

\draw [->] (0,0)--(1,0)  ;

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,\NbGrad} {%
    \coordinate (\x) at (\x/\NbGrad,0) ;
    \draw [very thin] (\x/\NbGrad,+2pt)--(\x/\NbGrad,-2pt) ;

    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{2 + \x / 10}
    \node[above=1pt]  at (\x)%
        {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,fixed,use comma]{\result}};

    } ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I want to add a "noze" to the axis `\draw [->] (0,0)--(1+5pt,0)  ;` doesn't work. How to do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  NbGrad/.store in=\NbGrad,
   }

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=6cm,font=\footnotesize,NbGrad=12]

\draw [->] (0,0)--(1,0)  ;

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,\NbGrad} {%
    \coordinate (\x) at (\x/\NbGrad,0) ;
    \draw [very thin] (\x/\NbGrad,+2pt)--(\x/\NbGrad,-2pt) ;

    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{2 + \x / 10}
    \node[above=1pt,text depth=0.5ex]  at (\x)%
        {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,fixed,use comma]{\result}};

    } ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As noted by Claudio, we can assign an initial value to NbGrad so that, in case no explicit definition is given afterwards, the document still compiles, like

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  NbGrad/.store in=\NbGrad,
  NbGrad=12,
   }
```

Comment: Thank's to both of you, both answers are acceptable. I pick up the shortest as `initial` isn't usefull in this case for me, but I note this possibilty for an other case.

Comment: @karlkoeller Done ;-) I don't now all the rules but obviusly your answer diserve an upvote. And I put a bookmark on it to use it in the future.

Comment: @Harish: after having stored the value into `\NbGrad`, you can add an intial value with `NbGrad=<something>` so that, in case no explicit definition is given afterwards, the document still compiles.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Nice suggestion. Thank you and added. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new pgf key with initial value 1

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/NbGrad/.initial=1}
```

and then create a new command `\NbGrad` that permits you to use its value:

```
\newcommand{\NbGrad}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/NbGrad}}
```

Note that, if you don't specify its value in your `tikzpicture`, the default value 1 is used.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/NbGrad/.initial=1}
\newcommand{\NbGrad}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/NbGrad}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=6cm,font=\footnotesize,NbGrad=12]

\draw [->] (0,0)--(1,0)  ;

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,\NbGrad} {%
    \coordinate (\x) at (\x/\NbGrad,0) ;
    \draw [very thin] (\x/\NbGrad,+2pt)--(\x/\NbGrad,-2pt) ;

    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{2 + \x / 10}
    \node[above=1pt]  at (\x)%
        {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,fixed,use comma]{\result}};

    } ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=6cm,font=\footnotesize]

\draw [->] (0,0)--(1,0)  ;

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,\NbGrad} {%
    \coordinate (\x) at (\x/\NbGrad,0) ;
    \draw [very thin] (\x/\NbGrad,+2pt)--(\x/\NbGrad,-2pt) ;

    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{2 + \x / 10}
    \node[above=1pt]  at (\x)%
        {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,fixed,use comma]{\result}};

    } ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]